# Переход к следующему слайду crocoblock по клику

Tags: slider

Есть слайдер https://crocoblock.com/widgets/slider/

как мне для другого элемента вне слайдера (какой-нибудь ссылки, например), прописать событие onclick, чтобы осуществлялся переход к следующему/предыдущему слайду в слайдере? Интересует именно реализация для слайдера crocoblock.

Пробовал отслеживать события в консоли:
"Открываем Chrome dev tools (F12) -> вкладка Sources -> Справа спойлер Event Listener Breakpoints -> Ставим галочку на событиях, которые нас интересуют" но так и не разобрался какая функция вызывается...

Как я понял, если у меня id слайдера "slider1", а кнопки "slider1_next", должно быть что-то вроде

```
<script>
$('#slider1_next').click(function() {
$( '#slider1' ).slider( 'nextSlide' );     
});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение. В crocoblock слайдеру присваиваем id, например, slider1. Тогда код будет такой:

```
jQuery('#slider1 .slider-pro').data('sliderPro').nextSlide();
```